# Best WildFly 8.2.0 Final upgrade options

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-8, infinispan

I'm running a WildFly server 8.2.0 Final at the moment, and using Infinispan caching a lot. In WildFly 9 Final are some optimisation to Infinispan and ofcourse other features, but i see there is also a WildFly 10 RC4 available.

What is the best option of upgrading my WildFly 8.2.0 Final server? I need a stable release so upgrade to WildFly 9, upgrade to 10 RC4 or same some time and wait till WildFly 10 Final release will come, or other recommendations?

Comment: I'm waiting WildFly 10 Final. Each version upgrade takes time, better to wait.

Comment: And then upgrade from 8.2.0 Final to 10 Final? Isn't it a risk upgrading to a just released Final version? Any idea's how long it will take till WildFly 10 Final will be released?

Comment: There are always risk for community version

Comment: I always prefer incremental, frequent upgrades.  WF 10 is currently targeted for early next year.  I would go with 9.0.2 (latest patch) and then 10 at a later point.  The jump from 8.2 -> 9 is bigger than 9 -> 10.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments and idea's